# Sorting lines according a column value

Tags: bash, csv, sorting

I need to sort all of the linnes in the csv filles according to the number contained in the second column from min to max, ignoring the first (header line):

```
ID(Prot),   ID(lig),    ID(cluster),    dG(rescored),   dG(before), POP(before)
10V1,   lig1,   1,  0.893101,   -7.2300,    36
10V1,   lig1,   3,  1.04024,    -6.5800,    4
10V1,   lig1,   4,  1.03044,    -6.5200,    7
10V1,   lig10,  1,  0.895754,   -6.0300,    47
10V1,   lig10,  2,  0.668236,   -5.9500,    112
10V1,   lig10,  3,  1.0103, -5.8200,    19
10V1,   lig1001,    1,  0.594972,   -5.6500,    142
10V1,   lig1001,    2,  1.05779,    -5.5000,    10
10V1,   lig1001,    3,  1.11195,    -4.9500,    2
10V1,   lig3,   1,  1.01583,    -5.6000,    20
10V1,   lig3,   2,  0.972203,   -5.2600,    36
10V1,   lig3,   3,  0.694967,   -5.2400,    118
10V1,   lig8,   1,  0.931977,   -7.4000,    25
10V1,   lig8,   2,  1.00413,    -7.1100,    9
```

should be sorted like lig1, lig3, lig8, lig10, lig1001 etc:

```
ID(Prot),   ID(lig),    ID(cluster),    dG(rescored),   dG(before), POP(before)
    10V1,   lig1,   1,  0.893101,   -7.2300,    36
    10V1,   lig1,   3,  1.04024,    -6.5800,    4
    10V1,   lig1,   4,  1.03044,    -6.5200,    7
    10V1,   lig3,   1,  1.01583,    -5.6000,    20
    10V1,   lig3,   2,  0.972203,   -5.2600,    36
    10V1,   lig3,   3,  0.694967,   -5.2400,    118
    10V1,   lig8,   1,  0.931977,   -7.4000,    25
    10V1,   lig8,   2,  1.00413,    -7.1100,    9
    10V1,   lig10,  1,  0.895754,   -6.0300,    47
    10V1,   lig10,  2,  0.668236,   -5.9500,    112
    10V1,   lig10,  3,  1.0103, -5.8200,    19
    10V1,   lig1001,    1,  0.594972,   -5.6500,    142
    10V1,   lig1001,    2,  1.05779,    -5.5000,    10
    10V1,   lig1001,    3,  1.11195,    -4.9500,    2
```

I've tried

```
sort -k2.4,2n "${csv}" > sorted.csv
```

but it did not recognize the values in second properly ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `sort` recognizes fields separated by non-blank to blank transitions. The second field of your second line (the first being the header) is not `lig1` nor `lig1,`, it's like    `lig1,`.

At first it's not clear if this field contains leading spaces or a tab character, because this site converts tabs to multiple spaces when *showing* code. The [raw source](https://superuser.com/revisions/05d82417-8a34-4c06-ad7b-9568cc4600b1/view-source) tells me the second field in each line contains one leading tab.

This tab character counts as the first character in the field, so your `-k2.4,2n` is off by one. It should be `-k2.5,2n`.

To reliably print the header first and not sort it, let something read and print it before `sort` processes the rest. It can be your shell:

```
{ IFS= read -r line; printf '%s\n' "$line"; sort -k2.5,2n; } <"${csv}"
```

or it can be `head`:

```
{ head -n 1; sort -k2.5,2n; } <"${csv}"
```

In my Debian 10 both commands work well when reading from a regular file. When reading from a pipe (e.g. `cat "${csv}" | { head …`), `head` apparently can read too much and drop excessive data (so `sort` won't get it, it's lost).

<sup>I *guess* `head` reads more even when reading from a regular file, it just seeks back to the right place before exiting, so the next tool can take over from there; this is obviously impossible with non-seekable input.</sup>

`read` is more careful and always reads one byte at a time, so it never reads too much.

Comment: Why not use -t, to tell sort to use comma instead of space as a field separator?  This still won't work if there are quoted fields in the file.

Comment: @user10489 What difference will it make?

Comment: If your fields contain spaces, it won't sort the correct column without -t,

Comment: @user10489 Have you tried this with the data in question (that really contains tabs, not spaces). I have, there is no difference. AFAIK `sort` does not use space as separator by default, it uses non-blank to blank transitions. If we use comma instead, the second fields will still start with a tab each. *Maybe* specifying `-t,` is good practice in this case even if there's no difference. Is it so? Show me the difference or explain more because for now I don't get you point.

Comment: I mispoke, by space I meant whitespace.  Also, some csv files contain no spaces.  Note that sort has a concept of both characters and fields, and if you define the field correctly (with using comma as a delimiter), you don't need to worry about character offsets.

Comment: @user10489 OK, so in general `-t,` is better for csv because there may be no blanks. This seems the good practice I hoped to learn from you. Now please show me a `sort` command that lets me not worry about character offsets for the specific data in question.

Comment: thank you very much sort -k2.5,2n works perfectly! just one question what is 2.5 there ?? could please precise these numbers in order that I could understand how it works precisely .. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @HotJAMS Have you read [`man 1 sort`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html)? (search for "KEYDEF is"). In the question you used `-k2.4,2n` as if you knew the basics. I'm not against helping you further but please read the the manual first. After you read it: what parts are unclear? I admit I don't know all the quirks. My answer (like many of my answers) involved me learning new things about the tool in question, reading documentation, testing and experimenting.